# PreferenceCategory condicional

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una app en la cual estoy usando Preference y me gustaría mostrar en PreferenceCategory solo un título de varios que estén disponibles , la selección del titulo podría ser mediante un condicional, pero como hacerlo, se puede?

Este es mi Preference.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="OPCION1"
    android:layout="@layout/setup_txt" >
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="OPCION2"
    android:layout="@layout/setup_txt" >
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="OPCION3"
    android:layout="@layout/setup_txt" >
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="OPCION4"
    android:layout="@layout/setup_txt" >
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agregar un android:key:

```
 <PreferenceCategory 
      android:title="OPCION1"
      android:key="opcion1" 
      android:layout="@layout/setup_txt" >
 </PreferenceCategory>
```

Para que en java lo localizes así:

```
 PreferenceCategory prefeCategory = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("opcion1");
  // código para if/else ...
 prefeCategory.setTitle("Tu_Nuevo_Titulo");
```